# Observable.take() causing NPE

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a simple program like this:

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getAcronyms()
                .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .flatMap(MainApp::getTitle)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

    }

    private static Observable<List<String>> getAcronyms(){
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("YOLO");
        strings.add("LMAO");
        strings.add("ROFL");
        strings.add("AYY LMAO");
        return new Observable<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super List<String>> observer) {
                observer.onNext(strings);
                observer.onComplete();
            }
        };
    }

    private static Observable<String> getTitle(String url) {
        return new Observable<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super String> observer) {
                observer.onNext(url + " title!");
                observer.onComplete();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This works fine, but when I chain a `take`:

```
getAcronyms()
        .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
        .flatMap(MainApp::getTitle)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .take(2)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

it prints 2 values but gives me an NPE:

> YOLO title!
>
> LMAO title!
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableTake$TakeObserver.onComplete(ObservableTake.java:83)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableTake$TakeObserver.onNext(ObservableTake.java:64)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFilter$FilterObserver.onNext(ObservableFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.tryEmit(ObservableFlatMap.java:262)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:559)
>     at MainApp$2.subscribeActual(MainApp.java:41)   at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)  at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.drainLoop(ObservableFlatMap.java:436)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.drain(ObservableFlatMap.java:323)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onSubscribe(ObservableFlatMap.java:546)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromIterable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromIterable.java:55)
>     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
>     at MainApp$1.subscribeActual(MainApp.java:31)   at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)  at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap.subscribeActual(ObservableFlatMap.java:55)
>     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap.subscribeActual(ObservableFlatMap.java:55)
>     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFilter.subscribeActual(ObservableFilter.java:30)
>     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableTake.subscribeActual(ObservableTake.java:30)
>     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)     at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10828)  at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10731)  at
>   MainApp.main(MainApp.java:18)

Could someone help me figure out why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception occurs due to `take`, after emitting defined number of items, internally tries to dispose `Disposable` object that is not set.

Thus you have to provide it when creating initial `Observable` by calling `observer.onSubscribe(disposable)` inside `subscribeActual` method implementation. But don't reinvent the wheel, moreover creating an `Observable` by calling its public constructor is meant for custom operators. Just use the static factory methods. In your case the best choice is  `Observable.fromCallable`:

```
private static Observable<List<String>> getAcronyms(){
    return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> call() throws Exception {
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            strings.add("YOLO");
            strings.add("LMAO");
            strings.add("ROFL");
            strings.add("AYY LMAO");
            return strings;
        }
    });
}
```

Also check this article: [RxJava 2 Disposable -  Under the hood](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/rxjava-2-disposable-under-the-hood-f842d2373e64)